# How to hide a window to system tray?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hide, system-tray

I'm developing a `Windows` app and within there is a django server running continously. Is there any possibility to hide the window to system tray from `cmd`? I don't want to use any external programms. I have a `.bat` script that starts the server and minimalizes the window to taskbar with this command :

```
START "runserver" /min python manage.py runserver
```

But I want to hide it to system tray, not taskbar. Is that possible?

Comment: [Minimize to Tray: 8 Ways to Minimize Any Program to Tray](https://www.actualtools.com/articles/detail.php?ID=888) or [What’s the Simplest Way to Minimize Applications to the System Tray?](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27007/whats-the-simplest-way-to-minimize-applications-to-the-system-tray/) etc.etc.

Comment: thanks @JosefZ for answering but as I said I don't want to use any external programms.

Comment: @madasionka Impossible in batch/cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide a console application because it does not actually have a window to hide, seeing as how it is running in the console (the console itself is just a window of the console, not the app running in it)